# Getting is document pinned or not on Visual Studio 2012 tab bar in extension

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I'm wondering is it possible to get is document pinned or not on VS tab bar, since this functionality was added only in 2012 VS it's hard to find any examples of people trying to do something with it. MSDN manual isn't helping on that matter either, because I guess the only way to find something about `envDTE` is through search.

I thought it should be stored somewhere in [EnvDTE.Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.document.aspx) or [EnvDTE.Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.window.aspx) objects but can't see anything related in there. But I'm probably missing something since they're not looking like they've been updated since the old Visual Studio versions.

So my question is - is there any way to achieve this kind of information?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "get is document pinned"?

Comment: @PeterRitchie In VS starting from 2012 you can press pin sign on document header in a tab bar so tabs with such documents would always stay in the beginning of the list. I probably should have written document tab pinned or document window pinned to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic IVsWindowFrame property to query for is [__VSFPROPID5.VSPROPID_IsPinned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vsfpropid5.aspx). So once you have an IVsWindowFrame, you can call GetProperty and that'll give you the pinned state.

Comment: Ok, I figured it all out, woohoo) On the other hand I still don't understand how could I find anything about it by myself initially, though maybe this is what actually called advanced usage :)

Comment: Well, yeah, experience helps here. The EnvDTE interfaces are very "simple" interfaces that don't expose most functionality, and they aren't updated for new features. For stuff like this, that's the last place to look. I myself guessed it was IVsWindowFrame property because that's where other tab properties live (like captions and such.)